# Whiter screen on MacBook Pro 2014

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, gpu

I have a MacBook Pro 15 inch, 2014 model, with 2 GPUs: Intel and NVIDIA 750M.

Last Monday I turned it on and I noticed that the screen is white as you can see in the picture.

I don't know what is the problem with it. I tried some solutions that I found on the web like resetting the NVRAM & SMC without result. I tried also to deactivate the dedicated GPU using gfxCardStatus but also no result.

The problem is that when I keep the Mac turned on for some time (>2 hours) the screen goes back to normal without white edges.

When I turn it off and keep it turned off for a while, then turn it on again it becomes white again and I must wait >2 hours so I can see my screen without this whiting effect.

[image]

Can you suggest a solution? We have no Apple Store or Apple repair in my country.

I tried to use my Mac HDMI but it's not working too. It was working before I got this problem. The mini DisplayPort to VGA is still working.

Comment: Start off by booting into Safe Mode and see if the problem persists.  Also try running [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Apple discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5619690)

> The problem is that the expose window is stuck. In order to force a
>   refresh take these steps:
>
> 1. launch terminal
> 2. type `killall Dock`

Comment: It's no longer Exposé - it's Mission control; but given that HDMI is also no longer working per the OP, it's highly doubtful a restart of the Dock will resolve the issue.  It's more likely a hardware problem

Answer (score -1):

This computer is slow, and can't keep up with the app. Click and hold the app Chrome, or Safari, or Fire fox. Press quit,then wait for a few seconds, reboot. There you are, this should work!

Comment: That seems to be a rather wild guess, a MBP from 2014 is perfectly able to handle the load coming from a few browser tabs.